# How can I deal with outdated versions of jQuery on a client site?

Tags: jquery

I've already run into clients running 1.3 code, when my work relied on 1.4's much improved features.

Yet these clients don't have the resources to update their old code ...

**Example**: The client refers to jQuery 1.3 in their site's template, but I'd really rather use 1.4 for my code and not have to try and use the older version.

Any thoughts on how to deal with this problem?

**Edit:** The ideal solution would be totally JS ... no server-side code as the client prefers it that way.

Comment: what exactly is your question? Can't you update the versions?

Comment: No, I cannot update the version. The client has code on their site which won't work with 1.4 --- Code I cannot edit and is not in the scope of my project --- The client doesn't the resources to fix their old page either.

Comment: @Justin then you are giving insufficient information for anybody to answer your question - the obvious answer is use 1.4 on your pages, and 1.3 on theirs. For tips how to achieve that you'll have to explain about your client's setup, what server side languages there are, what the templates look like, etc. etc.

Comment: @Pekka The problem is their "template" applies to all the pages on their site (and they use 1.3) It's not so much a server side issue, basically my pages need to work WITHIN their "template" ... but need to use 1.4 (and NOT break their existing pages.)

If that's not really possible that's fine, just looking for suggestions.

Comment: @Justin see my comments below, this is probably solvable somehow. The nicest I can think of if your pages were all in the same directory - you could parse the URL for that, and include 1.4 in that case.

Comment: @Pekka BTW, not all the pages in the site are in the dir ... but all MY pages are (and will always be) as I'm using cowboy's BBQ plugin http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ to use hash's like http://something.com/dir/#/home/ & http://something.com/dir/#/newpage etc ...

Comment: @Justin then find a way to embed the right jQuery dynamically as discussed below, and check against your `dir` for 1.4 and you should be good.

Comment: I am in the same situation. My client uses 1.11 and I have made a script using 3.4.1 :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and make the clients aware that the "resources" needed are typically pretty light.  Converting to a new version is usually a very quick process, unless they had a lot of erroneous code that was allowed before, but incorrect.

Have them take a look at the [release notes for 1.4](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14), and for that matter [1.4.1](http://jquery14.com/day-12/jquery-141-released) and [1.4.2](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/02/19/jquery-142-released/), the benefits of the upgrade *far* outweigh the time it takes to upgrade in every case I've come across.  The only caveat to this is in the 1.4 upgrade specifically, the added JSON strictness.  From the [1.4 release notes](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14):

> jQuery 1.3 and earlier used JavaScript’s eval to evaluate incoming JSON. jQuery 1.4 uses the native JSON parser if available. It also validates incoming JSON for validity, so malformed JSON (for instance `{foo: "bar"}`) will be rejected by jQuery in [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON) and when specifying “json” as the dataType of an Ajax request.

This means JSON operations are *much* faster, but old/invalid JSON won't cut it.  If they have to go fixing web-services because the JSON has to be absolutely valid in 1.4+, this could be a show-stopper on an upgrade for a large project...and I'm not sure what to tell you on that one.

As for plugins...every major/popular plugin supports new releases very quickly, if not they're pretty quick to fix yourself...and many just don't need any editing at all, because they weren't broken by the upgrade (still, check for new versions of a plugin, they may get performance boosts from a new version of core).

Comment: Thank you resource, and for the vote of confidence in 1.4 ... I too believe it would be worth the upgrade and that helps a lot.

Comment: FWIW, you could monkey-patch the jQuery.parseJSON(json) function to use the old eval() way if you really need support for broken JSON.

Comment: @Nick Craver This is true ... "strictly" speaking but actually a lot of custom code & plugins don't work as expected. It's not jQuery's fault really ... 1.3 is what, 1 1/2 years old?

Comment: @Justin - It is...but the time doesn't matter, it's how many changes in the release, and there weren't that many breaking changes from 1.3 to 1.4, can you give a few examples of breaks it creates?  I might be able to answer a bit narrower if I had some examples :)

Comment: @Nick Crave it seems to be mostly their (uhm not so great) custom code and some plugins that don't work ... and that's not really my problem it's theirs. Thanks for the offer tho.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking whether two versions of jQuery can be embedded into the same document at the same time, the answer is **no**.

Your client would have to upgrade, which should be relatively easy to do - if they're lucky, without any work at all: See @Nick's excellent overview.

Alternatively, if you need to use jQuery 1.4 on some pages, and 1.3 on others, you would certainly be able to set up some server-side shenanigans to serve the correct version. (It would probably even be possible using JavaScript.) but to do that, you'd have to give us more info about the setup.

Comment: I can modify the template: So, I guess it might be possible to put something on each page ... which could "notify" the *template* that it needs 1.4 (and tell it to **not** include 1.3) ... not sure about the performance repercussion of that however?

Comment: @Justin any server-side languages available? PHP? ASP?

Comment: @Justin can you write something into the `head` section of each file *before* jQuery is included, or can that be done only centrally in the template?

Comment: @Justin are *your* pages in their own directory?

Comment: @Pekka I could write something with jQuery 1.3 to the head AFTER 1.3 is included ... would that work? :) The client really doesn't want to use anything server side (more their issue then mine.) ASP.net (with PHP available) but they are weary of any server side stuff (I know wack.)

Comment: @Justin nope, once the `<script src....>` has been issued it is too late.... It would be very elegantly solvable in a server-side language by checking the current URL (`REQUEST_URI` in Apache). If it is in "your" app's directory, output the 1.4 `<script>` directive, otherwise the 1.3 one. If the directory is not an option to distinguish your project, then you'd have to come up with some naming convention for your pages `contactform.1-4.html` or whatever, you get my drift.

Comment: Hum since I can edit the template ... what if I wrapped the <script src....> of 1.3 in some JS script (clearly not in jQuery) that I could have MY page tell which version to load? And if the page didn't say which version to load, "else" to 1.3 ... am I crazy?

Comment: @Justin I thought about that as well, it should be possible. You could parse `location.href` or check your custom variable you specified before (`jquery_version = "1.4";`). It's only that `document.write()` doesn't work in the `head` AFAIK, so you'd have to create the script object using `createElement`. Probably possible - maybe worth a separate question.

Comment: @Pekka I will look into this, and see if that's the way to go. If so, I think you qualify as the "answer" anyhow & I will mark it as so. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you question. Do you have a website that uses JQuery? Surely if you put the JQuery javascript files in a folder in your web app and reference them in your script tags then the users' browers will download the new libraries.

Can you please explain what you mean when you say

> the clients don't have the resource to
>   update their old code.

Comment: In other words ... The client has many, many pages on their site that would break if upgraded to 1.4 (mostly due to bad code ...) so the entire template can't be upgraded as it would break said pages. However those pages have nothing to do with the newer project.

Comment: If it has nothing to do with the new project you are working on.. why worry about the pages using 1.3? work on your project with 1.4 as you are comfortable with it and follow Nick's advice on making the clients aware

Comment: 1.3 does have to do with my project in that 1.3 is included in the site wide template (which my pages need) ... and I need 1.4 on my page, and NOT 1.3